# How to turn list into string in bash?

Tags: bash, list

One silly question:

What I have now:

```
NA06994.del.vcf
NA07048.del.vcf
NA07056.del.vcf
NA11892.del.vcf
NA11893.del.vcf
NA12003.del.vcf
NA12043.del.vcf
```

How to turn into:

```
NA06994.del.vcf NA07048.del.vcf NA07056.del.vcf NA11892.del.vcf NA11893.del.vcf...
```

Comment: Are these in a variable? File?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's say that file named `a` has these contents:

```
NA06994.del.vcf
NA07048.del.vcf
NA07056.del.vcf
NA11892.del.vcf
NA11893.del.vcf
NA12003.del.vcf
NA12043.del.vcf
```

then, this command in bash will do what you want:

```
echo `cat a`
```

will result in this output:

```
NA06994.del.vcf NA07048.del.vcf NA07056.del.vcf NA11892.del.vcf NA11893.del.vcf NA12003.del.vcf NA12043.del.vcf
```

Comment: Leaving `$(cat a)` unquoted makes it susceptible to pathname expansion, which could alter the intended result.

Comment: Adding to @chepner's helpful comment: more generally, if the input file had line-internal whitespace, it would get normalized to a _single space_ each; generally, using an unquoted command substitution is a bad practice to promote, unless you clearly state its implications and limitations.

Answer (score 2):

Using awk, you can set the output record separator `ORS` to a space:

```
awk -v ORS=' ' '1' file
```

By default, the input record separator is a newline. This is removed by awk and replaced with `ORS` (a newline by default) when you use `print`. The script `1` is the shortest *true* condition, which triggers the default action `{ print }`.

It's marginally longer than using `echo` with `cat` but there are a number of advantages to this approach.

Firstly, white space in your file is preserved. This is because when you pass the result of `cat` to `echo`, it only sees the words in the file as a list of arguments, which it prints separated by a single space.

Secondly, there are no issues with special characters in your file, such as `*`, which would be glob-expanded by the shell before being passed to `echo`.

Thirdly, this all happens in a single process rather than making use of a subshell.

Comment: ++; however, it's worth mentioning that this will add a _trailing_ space to the output too.

Answer (score 0):

Given this question's generic title, here's how the solutions below *generalize*:

- The `paste` and `tr` solutions work with *single-character* separators only.
- The `awk` solution can work with *any character sequence (string)*.

---

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36817791/45375) points to the **simplest solution that also avoids a trailing space: `paste -s`:**

```
paste -sd ' ' file
```

- `-d ' '` tells `paste` to use a single space as the delimiter (separator)
- `-s` concatenates the lines of the input file using the specified separator *between* lines, but not after the last one.

---

An **`awk`** solution that **avoids a trailing space in the output**:

```
awk '{ printf "%s%s", sep, $0 } NR==1 { sep = " " } END { printf "\n" }' file
```

(The commands would also work *without* `NR==1`, yet less efficiently so, although it may not matter in the real world:
`awk '{ printf "%s%s", sep, $0; sep = " " }' file`)

- Uninitialized variables in `awk` default to the empty string in a string context, so `sep` is initially empty.

  - Thus, for the *first* line, string concatenation `sep $0` is effectively the same as just `$0`, the input line.
- `NR==1 { sep = " " }` sets variable `sep` to a single space, if the current line number (`NR`) is 1. Thus, *starting with line 2*, `sep` will be a single space, so that a single space is *prepended* to each subsequent input line on output.

The net effect is that a space is only inserted *between* input lines, but *not at the end*.
Omit `END { printf "\n" }` if you don't want a trailing *newline*.

---

A simple alternative using **`tr`**, **assuming a trailing space is not a problem**:

```
tr '\n' ' ' < file
```

<sup>Note that no trailing newline is output.</sup>

If you do need to remove the trailing space,

- with *GNU* `head`:

  `tr '\n' ' ' < file | head -c -1`
- otherwise, using shell parameter expansion:

  `str=$(tr '\n' ' ' < file)
   str=${str% }
   printf %s "$str"  # use '%s\n' to output a trailing newline`