# sed - removing last comma from listed value after doing a replace

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

I'm using `sed` to replace my file of new lines `\n` with `','` which works fine however, in my last item, I don't want the `,`.

How can I remove this?

Example:

```
sed 's/\n/,/g' myfile.out > myfile.csv
```

Output:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,
```

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/947404/sed-line-range-all-but-the-last-line ?

Comment: Since `sed` is _line_-based by default, you cannot match newlines this way; your command doesn't produce the output you quote. If you're using _GNU_ `sed`, use `-z`, as in Lars Fischer's answer; otherwise, you need a loop that reads all input lines up front.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well you can use labels:

```
$ cat file
1
2
3
4
5
6
$ sed ':a;N;s/\n/,/;ba' file
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

You can also use paste command:

```
$ paste -sd, file
1,2,3,4,5,6
```

Comment: ++ for the `paste` solution, which is not only simpler but also avoids the need to read the entire input file into memory first.

Answer (score 3):

<sup>Consider [jaypal singh's `paste` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36817791/45375), which is the most efficient and elegant.</sup>

An `awk` alternative, which doesn't require reading the entire file into memory first:

```
awk '{ printf "%s%s", sep, $0; sep = "," }' myfile.out > myfile.csv
```

If the output should have a trailing *newline* (thanks, [Ed Morton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1745001/ed-morton)):

```
awk '{ printf "%s%s", sep, $0; sep = "," } END { printf "\n" }' myfile.out > myfile.csv
```

- For the first input line, `sep`, due to being an uninitialized variable, defaults to the empty string, effectively printing just `$0`, the input line.
- Setting `sep` to `","` after the first `print` ensures that all remaining lines have a `,` prepended.
- `END { printf "\n" }` prints a trailing newline after all input lines have been processed. (`print ""` would work too, given that `print` appends the output record separator (`ORS`), which defaults to a newline).

The net effect is that `,` is only placed *between* input lines, so the output won't have a trailing comma.

Comment: Adding `awk -v ORS="" ... ` will remove the newlines from the output, too.

Comment: @LarsFischer: Thanks for the hint; that works fine, but it's actually easier to simply use `printf` instead of `print`; answer updated.

Comment: He didn't say it but I suspect the OP wants the output to end in a newline. If so then add `END{print ""}'`.

Comment: FWIW I'd always use `print ""` over `printf "\n"` as the former will work no matter what value `ORS` has while the latter would require you to remember to change that printf statement if/when you change `ORS`.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a second `s` command after the first: `sed -z 's/\n/,/g ; s/,$//`. This removes a comma at the end. (The option `-z` is from gnu sed and I needed it to get the first `s` command working.)

Comment: Just like the OP's own approach this won't work unless you precede the substitution commands with a loop that reads _all_ lines into the pattern space first.

Comment: @mklement0 for me the `-z` option of gnu sed works well without a loop: `sed -z 's/\n/,/g ; s/,$//' lines.txt `

Comment: ++ - that's a simple solution, but please add a note to point out that `-z` requires _GNU_ `sed`.